# Using same Monitor/Keyboard/Mouse on Laptop and Desktop

Tags: display, keyboard, mouse

I have the following:

- An HCL beanstalk desktop
- HP 6910 laptop
- HP docking station
- TFT monitor
- Keyboard
- Mouse

How do I connect all these so that I can use the same monitor, keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/): a software-based KVM over IP. It works great and is cross platform.

> Synergy lets you easily share your mouse and keyboard between multiple
>   computers on your desk, and it's Free and Open Source. Just move your
>   mouse off the edge of one computer's screen on to another. You can
>   even share all of your clipboards. All you need is a network
>   connection. Synergy is cross-platform (works on Windows, Mac OS X and
>   Linux).

[image]

Comment: they moved to http://synergy-foss.org/ ;)

Comment: I used to use the SF project [Win2Vnc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win2vnc/), it did the exact same thing and I loved it, it appears to have stopped development so this synergy looks like a good replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a hardware KVM switch. With that you can use a keyboard, video (monitor) and mouse with multiple devices.

Comment: Otherwise known as a KVM (Keyboard, Video, Mouse) switch.